# How to complete user task based on assignee in Camunda Parallel User Task

Tags: camunda, bpmn, camunda-modeler

I have created a Camunda workflow, where there is a parallel user task exist. If I try to complete the user task, it is completing the user task based on the order given in the list. Ex: {"John", "Max", "Jassica"}. If I complete user task once, it is considering that John have completed the user task.

Is there a way I can tell Camunda that "Hey this is the user who completed the user task."?

Am trying to get the list of pending user task for each user.
Ex: {"John", "Max", "Jassica"} are the list of assignees in my parallel user task.

When I initiate the workflow, each user will be assigned with 1 pending task.

```
taskService.complete(taskIds, processVariables);
```

using this code, I will complete the user task, but it is not specific to any assignee. Even am completing the task as Max, it is still considering John, so pending task will become 0 for John and 1 for Max.

I want to complete the user task by specific assignee.

Answer (score 0):

You should claim the task with the userId who is working on it.
Typically, it is a good idea to claim early, so when you start working on a task, you call `taskService.claim(taskId, userId)`, because then you can exclude this task from other users taskslists and avoid double work.

But it is also fine to do a "late-claim", so directly before you call `complete`, just call `claim`.

How you get the userId to use for the claim is up to you and typically requires accessing the web authorization to get the logged in user from a token or a session.

Comment: But my use case is all 3 must approve and if one user reject then flow should not wait for rest of the users, it should move to next step, if one user approves then count of pending task to that particular user should be reduced by one. But issue am facing is I couldn't tell camunda that this is the particular user that have completed his user task. Claim is not working at this point as it is already claimed.